# How to find and select a time-zone in Google Calendar create event

Tags: google-calendar, time-zone

When interactively (not programmatically) creating an event in Google Calendar, I can click on the time-zones link to see a list of 100s of time zones. However, I don't see any way (at least in Mac Safari) to search for a time-zone, neither by the time-zone name, nor by the target city.

Is there a better way than just meticulously searching this very long list?

Answer (score 0):

No.

I thought that I should shorten my answer knowing that you are adverse to long lists. ;)

Of course, you could submit a [feature request](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110973?hl=en&ref_topic=10510448) but Calendar has been around for a long time and changes are few and far between.

Answer (score -1):

Command-F: Find items in a document works.

Comment: No, CMD-F brings up a search window, and typing 'Eastern' shows 46 matches, but pressing the forward and back icons > and < do nothing to the popup menu shown 100s of time zones.